# How to trigger a function with textInput binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout.js 3.3.0. In my viewmodel I have a lot of data rows that I present in a table with a foreach binding. In every row there is a text input that is bound to an observable. What I want to achieve is this: whenever the text changes, it should be send into an inline function so that I can process the changes. This is my input:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="
    textInput: MyText(),
    event: { 
        keyup: function(data, event) { console.log(data.MyText()); }
    }" />
```

The above code does not output anything and I'm getting no errors. How do I have to change the binding in order to see changes in `MyText()` immediately on the console, for example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you doing this such way? Maybe better would be to subscribe to observable property MyText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making your binding "one-way" with writing `textInput: MyText()` because you are binding to its value and to the observable itself.

That is why the `event` binding is not logging correctly.

So you just need to remove the `()`

```
<input type="text" data-bind="
    textInput: MyText,
    event: { 
        keyup: function(data, event) { console.log(data.MyText()); }
    }" />


<span data-bind="text: MyText" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txat5h5a/).

Comment: Yay! Now I got it. Thanks alot!